# Navigation Issue in UWP

Tags: navigation, uwp, windows-10

**tl;dr**

I have 3 Pages `MainPage.xaml`, `BlankPage1.xaml`, `BlankPage2.xaml` with `Button` on `MainPage` and `BlankPage1` that navigates to `BlankPage1` and `BlankPage2` Respectively. I enabled System Back Button so that i can go back to previous page.

`Button` Tap on `MainPage` navigates to `BlankPage1` and `Button` Tap on `BlankPage1` navigates to `BlankPage2`. This works fine.

**Problem:** When I tap `Back Button` on `BlankPage2` it goes back to `BlankPage`. Now when I tap the `Button` on `BlankPage1` it goes to `BlankPage2` but when i Tap the `Back Button`, instead of going to `BlankPage1` it navigates directly to `MainPage`.

**Below is my code.**

*MainPage.xaml*

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="GoTo Page 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        }
    }
}
```

*BlankPage1.xaml*

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App2.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="GoTo Page 2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

*BlankPage1.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, a) =>
                {
                    if (Frame.Content.GetType() == typeof(BlankPage1))
                    {
                        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
                        {
                            Frame.GoBack();
                            a.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));
        }
    }
}
```

*BlankPage2.xaml*

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App2.BlankPage2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="Final Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

*BlankPage2.xaml.cs*

```cs
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, a) =>
                {
                    if (Frame.Content.GetType() == typeof(BlankPage2))
                    {
                        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
                        {
                            Frame.GoBack();
                            a.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you navigate to a page, the `OnNavigatedTo` method is being called and you're registering a new handler for the `BackRequested` event, meaning it'll execute multiple times when you press the back button. You should unsubscribe to that event in your `OnNavigatedFrom` method of each page.

Setting `Handled = true` doesn't mean that other subscriptions for that event won't be executed, it just means:

> If you don't mark the event as handled, the system decides whether to navigate away from the app (on the Mobile device family) or ignore the event (on the Desktop device family).

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the answer from @Decade Moon, I would suggest you could even centralize the logic into the `App` class for easier manageability and cleaner `Page` code-behinds.

Add the following line to `App.OnLaunched` method:

```cs
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += App_BackRequested;
```

And implement the handler like this:

```cs
private void App_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = ( Frame )Window.Current.Content;
    if ( frame.CanGoBack )
    {
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

We grab the frame of the current window and check if we can navigate back. In case it is possible, we handle the event and navigate. The advantage of this is, that you can now remove all `BackRequested` related actions on all pages.

You can also do similar thing for the `AppViewBackButtonVisibility`: add the following to the end of `OnLaunched`:

```cs
rootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated;
```

And now implement the handler as:

```cs
private void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        frame.CanGoBack ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                          AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;            
}
```

Each time the frame navigates, the visibility of the back button will automatically update.